# Laravel and video mp4

Tags: laravel, web, video

I have a website with Laravel and I want to insert a video (mp4) but the video not working.

place the video in the public directory and in storage / public / video call it with:

```
 <video src="videos/people.mp4" autoplay="" loop=""></video>
```

Comment: The [public directory](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk) is `storage/app/public` and has to be set up with `php artisan storage:link`. You probably want a non-relative URL to the file, too - the `asset()` or `url()` helper can assist you there.

Comment: Is it placed in `public/video` or `public/videos`? Also, your `src` is relative to the current page, so if you're on anything other than `/` you would need to change the html to `src="/videos/people.mp4"`

Answer (score 1):

Something is missing in your code, change it to:

```
<video controls width = "500">
        <source src = "{{asset ('videos/people.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

**• If you want an auto-read, add "autoplay muted" :**

```
<video autoplay muted controls width = "500">
        <source src = "{{asset ('videos/people.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

**• And finally, if you want autoplay and repeat, add "loop" :**

```
<video autoplay muted loop controls width = "500">
        <source src="{{asset ('videos/people.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4"></video>
```